# How can we set different API endpoints in Xcode Cloud for our project

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud

I am working on a project where I need to choose between three end points for API:

- .app
- .cloud
- .com

I am not sure about how can I do this while either archivng the app itself in Xcode without having to change the end point in a Constant file for example. Or achieve the same result in Xcode Cloud CI CD.

I don't see any option to set or choose API endpoints in Xcode Cloud

Comment: I can’t speak to Xcode Cloud, specifically, but I generally do this with separate targets and/or schemes. Do you not have these capabilities with Xcode Cloud?

Comment: I have tried doing this via Schemes, ex- Staging, Debug etc, but it is not working in Xcode Cloud. It is an important feature and I am surprised to see it has some very big bugs.